# Extracting tag value from a JSON string field in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have an Oracle column that stores a JSON string. This is an example value

```
{
    "data": {
        "employer": {
            "status": "active",
            "name1": {
                "content": "My favorite company"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in getting the value of the content tag that is contained in the first occurrence of name1 tag. So in this example, what I want is to get "My favorite company" (without the quotes)

How do I do this in Oracle SQL query?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Oracle introduced native JSON querying in 12.2.

Comment: Older :-(
We are on 11g

Comment: Bummer. I've seen some open source PL/SQL JSON parsers online. I have never used any of them so I can't recommend any one in particular. You could also try writing your own regular expression formulas, which is probably as close to a JSON parser as you can get without some serious coding effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 12.2 or higher, you may use [the SQL/JSON function `JSON_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html), as seen in the below query -

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(YOUR_COLUMN, '$.content')
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; should be OK if JSON data is *simple*, but - that's what your example suggests:

```
SQL> select * from test;

JSON
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "data": {
        "employer": {
            "status": "active",
            "name1": {
                "content": "My favorite company"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

- `temp` CTE finds `"content"` string and returns everything that follows
- the final query extracts what's between  3rd and 4th double quotes character

---

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select substr(json,
  3                   instr(json, '"content"')
  4                  ) content
  5     from test
  6    )
  7  select substr(content,
  8                instr(content, '"', 1, 3) + 1,
  9                instr(content, '"', 1, 4) - instr(content, '"', 1, 3) - 1
 10               ) result
 11  from temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My favorite company

SQL>
```